# Checked Property of Checkbox Added Dynamically in ASP.NET Application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net

I have a webpage where I am dynamically creating a table based on some user inputs. Each row has a checkbox that indicates whether the user wants to select that row or not and I want this checkbox to be automatically checked if the user edits anything in the row (Because if they are editing it they would want to select it). So I am using javascript with jquery to set the 'checked' property to true.

However, for some reason when I add a checkbox to my page dynamically this way it does not allow me to use

`$(<selector>).prop('checked', true)`

And I know the problem is not the selector because when I use the same selector to show/hide the checkboxes, everything works as expected. Also, I know the prop('checked', true) syntax is the correct choice because when I do this to a checkbox just added directly to my webpage it works. And I have the javascript within a $(document).ready function so I do not understand why it will not work for my dynamically added checkboxes.

This is the code that adds the checkbox:

```
var checkCell = new TableCell();
var checkbox = new CheckBox { ID = "checkbox" + i, CssClass = "checkbox-class" };
checkCell.Controls.Add(checkbox);
tr.Cells.Add(checkCell);
...
contentTable.Rows.Add(tr);
```

Comment: Try to add for your checkbox the property ClientIDMode="Static".